# Android ListView NullPointerException on setAdapter()

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception

During initializing my navigation drawer components, android throws null pointer exception. I can not figure it out why I get this. Please explain first what is the problem and then solution. Thanks in advance.

Here is my stack trace:

```
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842): Process: com.prome.orcadirectory, PID: 1842
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.prome.orcadirectory/com.prome.orcadirectory.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at com.prome.orcadirectory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-21 17:24:15.632: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):     ... 11 more
```

Here is line number 82:

```
 listView.setAdapter( myAdapter );
```

listView and myAdapter is initialized in onCreate method of main activity at line 60 and 80 as:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_left);
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

here is MyAdapter Class:

```
/* ----- Navigation Drawer Components ----- */
//custom array adapter class
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    // drawer String array and Drawable icon array
    private String[] drawerList;
    private int[] icons = { R.drawable.ic_action_group,
            R.drawable.ic_action_search,
            R.drawable.ic_action_person,
            R.drawable.ic_action_add_person,
            R.drawable.ic_action_about,
            R.drawable.ic_action_back };

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        drawerList = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_list);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return drawerList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return drawerList[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = null;
        if( convertView == null ) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        TextView titleText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.drawerTextView);
        ImageView titleImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.drawerImage);

        titleText.setText(drawerList[position]);
        titleImage.setImageResource(icons[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
/* ----- Navigation Drawer Components ends ----- */
```

navigation_drawer.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_left"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawerImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/drawerTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textColor="#981717"
    android:textAppearance="@android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Orca Directory</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="msg1">Loading Contents. Please wait#8230;</string>
<string name="login_name">User name</string>
<string name="login_pass">Password</string>
<string name="login">Log In</string>
<string name="msg_cancel">Cancel</string>
<string name="msg_quit">Quit</string>
<string name="drawer_open">Drawer Opened</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Drawer Closed</string>

<string-array name="drawer_list">
    <item>All members</item>
    <item>Search member</item>
    <item>Profile</item>
    <item>Update Profile</item>
    <item>About</item>
    <item>Quit</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Where have you initialised myAdapter?

Comment: Please add your layout file.

Comment: Clean your project (e.g., Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu)

Comment: myAdapter has been initiated, layout files has been added, tried with clean, but no progress, still not working..